# parameter types -> return type

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
same_dimensions: (Picture, Picture) -> Boolean
```

I need to create two pictures have both of them have equal height and width and it'll return `True`, or `False` if not. How do I start this?

Also, I need to do

```
copyright:() -> Picture
```

To return a new 20 pixel by 20 pixel Picture that has a white background, a black 16 by 16 oval and position `(0,0)`, and a black letter `C` (upper case) at position `(6,3)`. I have no idea how to position these things.

[edited] I am working on the first function
import media

```
def same_dimensions(pic1, pic2):
```

thats what i have down so far, my prof said that we can name the pictures ourselves.

Comment: Did your instructor tell you what libraries you can use? I don't think `Picture` is a built-in type in python.

Comment: You'll need to help us out for us to help you. What are the requirements? What libraries are you supposed to load (i.e. does it mention any `import` statements)? Popular libraries for something like this might be `matplotlib` (`pylab`) or the `PIL` (Python Image Library).

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/89hftsa thats the link to the exercise of what im supposed to do, sorry, Im completely new at this so i am just getting familiar with it. But Apparenly we have to create two pictures.

Comment: From the look of the site, there's a particular library you should be using (media?). This, as far as I know, is not a standard library. It might be something your professor wrote for your exercises. Without knowing more about the library, we can't really help you.

Comment: hmmm, well its from the media library. we had to download pygraphics and all that. Oh, i thought everyone uses the same thing? Im so sorry Im just so confused. The things the teacher wanted us to download is Wing, Python, nose, and pygraphics.

Answer (score 1):

The picture library usually used with Python is PIL (Python Image Library).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Image` module from `PIL`:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im1 = Image.new('RGBA', (10,10))
>>> im2 = Image.new('RGBA', (10,10))
>>> im3 = Image.new('RGBA', (15,12))
>>> im1.size == im2.size
True
>>> im1.size == im3.size
False
```

Comment: but we never learnt that tho, thats why I am geeting sort of confused. :(

we use the media, so wat I thought to do was to do:
def same_dimensions(pic1,pic2)
    pic1=media.choosefile()
    pic2=media.choosefile() 
is that wrong?